# IntelliJ/Clojure: shortkey for Sync Files in REPL

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I want to find the keybinding for "Sync Files in REPL". 
I can find the keybinding for this action in:

```
File -> Settings -> Keymap -> CLojure Keybinding -> Bind Set: Cursive
```

I see that the keybinding for this action is `Ctrl+Shift+M`. However, when I use this keybinding, nothing happens. Do you have any idea why and how to use the keybinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. This github [issue](https://github.com/cursive-ide/cursive/issues/552#issuecomment-60475268) explains it:

> The Clojure->Keybindings panel isn't where you make general changes to
>   the key mappings for actions - you'll find that in the generic
>   IntelliJ Keymap panel. The Keybindings panel is for setting a bunch of
>   key mappings in bulk - it's something you'll only do probably once
>   when you're initially setting Cursive up. For changing mappings for
>   particular actions after that point, you'll use the Keymap panel.

If you look in `KeyMap` (**not** `Clojure Keybindings`), make a new keymaps profile (or copy one of the existing ones), and the go to `Plug-ins -> Cursive -> Sync files in REPL`. The key binding specified there should work (unless of course you have it set to something that conflicts with something else).